# Reactivate previously activated window/program applescript?

Tags: macos, terminal, applescript

I have a script that activates firefox, refreshes the page, waits 60 seconds, then does it again, in an infinite loop. How would I get it to go back to what was active before?

So say I have firefox in the background with a question about Applescripting on StackOverflow up, but while I wait for a response, I'm playing a game. How do I get it to, after going to firefox and refreshing, come back to the game?

Code:

`i="0"`

`while [ $i == 0 ]`

`do`

`osascript -e 'tell application "Firefox" to activate'`

`osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to key code 15 using command down'`

`pause 10`

*go back to previous window*

`sleep 60`

`done`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're already using System Events, use it to hide the application.

```
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "h" using command down
```